# packer vmware-iso export to single file

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, vmware-fusion, packer

I am using virtualbox-iso and vmware-iso builders. I am on Mac, so vmware-iso runs with vmware fusion.

Virtualbox-iso out is a single .ova file.

But the vmware-iso output is actually a bunch of files. Also could not figure out a way to import them.

How do I make packer export the vmware-iso output into a single importable output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/1593

Apparently packer exports only .vmx format for vmware.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to go the [plugin route](https://www.packer.io/docs/extend/plugins.html), the following [post-processor](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/post-processors.html) will do what you need:

[packer-post-processor-ovftool](https://github.com/iancmcc/packer-post-processor-ovftool)

It uses VMWare's command-line `ovftool` to add the ability to Packer to convert `.ovf` files (actually multiple files within a single folder) into a single `.ova` file.  Simply configure your packer template as such:

```
{
    "post-processors": [{
        "type": "ovftool",
        "only": ["vmware"],
        "format": "ova"
    }]
}
```

If you don't like that route, [apparently](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/282106?start=0&tstart=0) `.ova` files are just tar files of the entire `.ova` directory.  You could use Packer's [compress](https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/compress.html) post-processor to compress the VMWare build output into a single tar archive and then just rename the file extension from `.tar` to `.ova`.  You would configure that as follows:

```
{
    "post-processors": [{
        "type": "compress",
        "only": ["vmware"],
        "output": "actuallyAnOVA.tar"
    }]
}
```